# Flutter - How to remove HTML tags from text and display it?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, controller

I'm trying to display some data from API. Data is text inside the **body**.

How to remove HTML tags from it and display only text?

Code:

```
Text(
                productController.privacypolicy.value.data!.shop!.privacyPolicy!.body.toString(),
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      color: Color(0xff1b1b1b),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: 16,
                      letterSpacing: 0.5)),
```

Comment: you need to use Webview to render html.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't have that much experience with HTML. How to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Webview https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter
feed the html String and render it.

Or Other Simpler way is to use.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html
Example:

```
Widget html = Html(
  data:  productController.privacypolicy.value.data!.shop!.privacyPolicy!.body.toString(), //Your String.     
);
```